# Add Footer to CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to add a Footer to `CoordinatorLayout` which contains a `TabView + ViewPager`.

**Here is the main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.entree.entree.activity.StoreActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tray"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_find"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#00000000"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_above="@+id/llTray" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_search"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_search_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**And here is the Xml Content:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/container"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.entree.entree.activity.StoreActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/divider"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTray"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tray_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/view_tray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTotalPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Rs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The footer is in xml content.

If i remove:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in the main Xml `View Pager`, footer appears , else it's not shown.

How can i get the footer visible?

Comment: Please check this blog-  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: @AdarshYadav no this doesnt work in coordinatorlayout

Comment: Do you want to show that footer all the time ? or just in viewpager?

Comment: all the time @LinX64.. rigth now its on a click.. but later it will be always be ter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

With `match_parent` for both `height` and `width` which it doesn't seems to be good.

Also, Perhaps you will need to show that `ViewPager` with `NestedScrollView` for scrolling the content in future.(needs a trick, but you can achieve this).

So, my suggest is, you should be able to show that footer all the time in the below of that `ViewPager` by adding it like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llTray" />

        <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FC0"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Fixed Footer"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This should show the footer all the time (*even when `ViewPager` is collapsing*).

---

Or if you want to show it in your `ViewPager`:

you should add this in your contents:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Which means, it will put the contents below the `AppbarLayout`

Anyways, your contents problem is coming from that `GridView` like i said, it will match all the content and you don't have `ScrollView` or even `NestedScrollView` to show the other contents.

Comment: Thanx @LinX64 it worked...What i still dont understand is the use of appbar_scrolling_view_behavior. can u just brief me

Comment: It is using for putting a view below the `AppbarLayout`.you're welcome.take a look: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html

Comment: This has issues with appbarlayout, I am using nestedscrollview instead of viewpager, it doesnt scroll till the end of the scroller though